# Generate HTML file using JSP template

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, jsp, servlets

How is it possible to generate HTML file using Servlet/JSP?

I'm using Spring MVC to create a service. This service would get some data from the database. Then I'd like it to read a JSP template from somewhere else, not from WEB-INF. There are attributes which are the data from the database that would be passed in upon reading this template. Then it should return a string which includes the source of JSP. This string should now contain the data which replaces the JSP variables. Finally, this string should be written to a file (.html file).

I can't find a tutorial about it. Instead, i noticed mostly the JSP file is being dispatched as response and displayed on the browser.

Please help. Thannks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring with Thymeleaf.

Thymeleaf is a Java-based library used to create a web application. It provides good support for serving an XHTML/HTML5 in web applications. In this chapter, you will learn in detail about Thymeleaf.

Tutorial from Thymeleaf:- [click here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_thymeleaf.htm)